# Transitive Amstrong Rules

Tags: database-theory

I have R={A,B,C,D,E} with functional dependencies ABCD → E and AC → ABCD,with Axiom of transitivity rule is AC → E a transitive dependency? Thanks before and sorry for this simple question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition of transitive dependency -

A functional dependency is said to be transitive if it is indirectly formed by two functional dependencies. For e.g.

X -> Z is a transitive dependency if the following three functional dependencies hold true:

```
X->Y
Y does not ->X
Y->Z
```

Given, ABCD->E and AC->ABCD, or simply AC->BD

So, ABCD -> E can be written as AC -> E, as AC->BD.

So, the transitive rule is not required to prove AC -> E

Also, if we take X= AC, Y=ABCD, then X->Y (given) but X is subset of Y

So, Y->X (failing the second rule for transitivity)